# Multiple raster file statistics

Tags: arcpy, raster, cell-statistics

This is the code to find the maximum value in multiple raster files. Is there a way to batch run the code?

```
work_dir = r'E:\GEE_processing\VIIRS\test_16dy\data'

result = r'E:\GEE_processing\VIIRS\test_16dy'
folder_name= "max_16"
arcpy.CreateFolder_management(result, folder_name)

arcpy.env.workspace= work_dir
raster = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "img")

doy_01 = raster[0],raster[1]
print(doy_01)
doy_02 = raster[2],raster[3]
print(doy_02)
doy_03 = raster[4],raster[5]
print(doy_03)
doy_04 = raster[6],raster[7]
print(doy_04)
doy_05 = raster[8],raster[9]
print(doy_05)

outws = result+'\\'+folder_name

arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(doy_01, outws+"\\"+raster[0][0:24]+'_max.img', "MAXIMUM", "DATA")
arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(doy_02, outws+"\\"+raster[2][0:24]+'_max.img', "MAXIMUM", "DATA")
arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(doy_03, outws+"\\"+raster[4][0:24]+'_max.img', "MAXIMUM", "DATA")
arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(doy_04, outws+"\\"+raster[6][0:24]+'_max.img', "MAXIMUM", "DATA")
arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(doy_05, outws+"\\"+raster[8][0:24]+'_max.img', "MAXIMUM", "DATA")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. The meaning of "automatically" is subject to opinion. I suggest you [Edit] the Question to clarify your exact meaning.

Comment: Use a for loop: `for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*", "img"):` Then you dont need to fiddle with indexes